# Why can't I increment models.IntegerField?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I want to have a counter field in my user profile model to see how many requests each user has made.

However I cannot figure out how to increment the count.

I am trying to increment an integer field which is a associated with a model which looks like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    request_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Then in my views I want to increment the request_count every time the user makes a request like so:

```
def updateProfile(request, email):
     user = User.objects.get(email=email)
     form = forms.ProfileForm(request.POST)
     if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            form.save()
            try: 
                user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
                user_profile.request_count += 1
                user_profile.save()
            except:
                user_profile = None
            return redirect('index')
```

```
<a href="{% url 'update-profile' session.userinfo.email %}">
Update my profile
</a>
```

For some reason every time I run this it sets the request_count to 1.

I assume this is because it is defaulting to 0 (the default I set) and then adding 1 to that.

But why doesn't the value increment?

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: i am not sure of the actual reason but user and profile are one to one and once the  record is saved i don't think another data can be added just making you conscious

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean? Why wouldn't I be able to override data?

Comment: Demonstrated code is not enough to reproduce your case, please show more code and elaborate how you check results. Especially how `pk` is initialized.

Comment: one user cannot have multiple profile as per your model that is what i mean to say

Comment: @lordstock yes I am aware of that. Thanks.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I have added more context to the views.py file

Comment: I'm afraid this still does not explain how you initialize `pk` or how you check result and the scenario is still not reproducible.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I'll add detail but this really is not important as I can save data to the correct object. It's simply the wrong VALUE that is being saved (as described).

Comment: Shown piece of code looks fine, same as what @benjamin_morgues suggested (his approach is more accurate). In short: your story is not true or incomplete. Shown code never gets executed or this is not all what happens during save or reading code is wrong or displaying template is broken. So details matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it turned out that saving my ModelForm was, for some reason, resetting the count variable even though the count field wasn't part of the modelform. What fixed it was changing the ordering to set the instance first, then save the form, then save the profile with the count variable.

The final solutions looks like this:

```
Def updateProfile(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(email=pk)if form.is_valid():
        try:
            user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
            user_profile.ai_count +=1
        except:
            user_profile = None
        profile = form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = user
        profile.save()
        user_profile.save()
        return redirect('index')
```

Not entirely sure why this works, but it does.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with [F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions)

```py
def updateProfile(request, pk):
     user = User.objects.get(email=pk)
     user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
     user_profile.request_count = F("request_count") + 1
     user_profile.save()

     return redirect('index')
```

If you want to access the value after that, you should use refresh_from_db.

Comment: Is there maybe an error in this? This statement returns 'Value(0) + F(request_count) + Value(1)'

Comment: Ha indeed, sorry I missed that I kept the `+=`, it's only `=` , I edited the answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for me unfortunately. I get the same result as described in the issue.

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seem right, I'm quite sure this should update your database. Could provide us a minimal reproducible example please? Maybe the key to this problem is somewhere else. How do you check that it didn't change ?

Comment: I'm just checking in the Django backend. If I manually change it to 4 and then run again and save it saves the number 1. This leads me to think that for some reason it's defaulting to 0 each time and then adding 1 and saving it. I just can't figure out why. Does this have to do Integers being immutable?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that kinda looks weird is this:

```
user = User.objects.get(email=pk)
```

Unless you're using a custom user model, email isn't the primary key. The only required fields in the default user model are username and password. So maybe it's having trouble finding an user.

If it's not that, maybe you could try to update that field specifically:

```
user_profile.save(update_fields=['request_count'])
```